# Content in webview is not rendering on scroll on Android L and M

Tags: android, user-interface, webview, rendering

Steps:

1. Loading an website in WebView control. This goes fine.
2. I call a JavaScript method, which fetches new content.

Issue:
After step# 2, I can see content rendered in view port. But once I scroll down (or right), content doesn't render, I see only empty white/grey area. Though I know that content is there.

This bug is seen on Android OS with version >= 5.0. On KitKat, it working perfectly fine.

Also, in uiautomatorviewer I can see that there are VIEW elements with non-zero co-ordinates. These VIEW elements are the one which were in View port before scroll. Along with such VIEW elements I see other VIEW elements which have co-ordinates (hence height, width) = 0.

Below is the code snippet:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw(); // issue not getting resolved with or without this line of code
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(), "external");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl(myServiceUrl);
    }
```

Enabling/disabling hardware rendering also didn't help.

Is this a known issue? Any fix/word around?

WebView version - 46.0.2490.76

Comment: As the WebView from Android Lollipop and up are based off of the Chromium project, does your problem occur in Chrome for Android app?

Comment: @MorrisonChang
I am using android.webkit.WebView in my Application. Basically I am having an Activity, which is hosting a WebView control. In onCreate() of Activity, I am calling webView.loadUrl(mySiteUrl). It is working fine on Android OS version < 5 (e.g. Kitkat). having issue starting with Android L and then M.
In my question, I have already provided, WebView/Chrome version as 46.0.2490.76.
Let me know what more info is required?

Comment: @MorrisonChang, precise answer to your question is - I am facing this problem in an Android app.

Comment: I think what MorrisonChang means is that you should try loading the URL in your device Chrome browser, if the same thing happens, it's probably a problem of your html page, not your Android app.

Comment: @XiaoyuYu, basically, I am first loading a url and then invoking a javaScript method which fetch some content. And problem is after that content is fetched with JS method. Not sure how can I do it in default chrome browser on Android.

Comment: Use Remote Debugging - both WebView and Chrome for Android - https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging to figure out what is going on with your html/javascript. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: Found out that issue was not on client side but on web side, and it was related to a layer's visibility and it is fixed on web side. And now content is rendering.